# Using column-wise operations in dplyr to divide multiple column values by a specified row

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I use column-wise operations in `dplyr` to divide multiple column values by a specified row? This question has been answered several times for the case of individual columns, but I am trying to find a solution for multiple columns using `dplyr`'s column-wise `across` function. (The only relevant answers that I could find use the superseded `mutate_at` function.)

Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish, using a toy dataset:

```
library(dplyr)

df_pre <- tribble(~name, ~q_1, ~q_2,
              "max", 5, 4,
              "a", 4, 2,
              "b", 3, 1)
```

I want to divide each value in each column prefixed **q_** by the value in the row for which **name** = "max". I can do this individually for each column:

```
df_post <- df_pre %>% 
  mutate(q_1 = q_1 / q_1[name == "max"]) %>% 
  mutate(q_2 = q_2 / q_2[name == "max"])
```

But my attempt to do the same thing using a column-wise operation throws an error:

```
df_post <- df_pre %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("q_")), ~ .x / .x[name == "max"])
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..2`.
#> ℹ `..2 = ~.x/.x[name == "max"]`.
#> x `..2` must be a vector, not a `formula` object.
```

What am I doing wrong with the last line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`across`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) should be closed after the `.fns`

```
library(dplyr)
df_pre %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("q_"), ~ .x / .x[name == "max"]))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name    q_1   q_2
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 max     1    1   
2 a       0.8  0.5 
3 b       0.6  0.25
```

---

The usage of `?across` is

> across(.cols = everything(), .fns = NULL, ..., .names = NULL)

Comment: Thanks as always @akrun. Is there a reason that you use a "." in "~ ." rather than ".x"?

Comment: @nicholas It is just by habit.  I think the correct notation is `.x` and `.` is kind of general.  When you have more than one input i.e. in `map2` or `imap`, it is better to use `.x` and `.y`